# knex how to select row in certain time stamp range

Tags: knex.js

My table is like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE `product_name` (
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
) ;
```

My input is like this `const input = '2021-09-28T15:12:22.000Z'`

I want to use knex to select all the row that has `updated` time bigger than my input. How to do that that in knex ?

My take doesn't work

```js
const results = await kx(table.trackings)
            .select()
            .where('updated', '>', input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const results = await kx(table.trackings)
            .select()
            .whereRaw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated) >?', [moment(input).unix()])
            .orderBy('id', 'desc')
```

just use the `.whereRaw` fucntion and convert time stamp to seconds we we can compare them.